# flask application, how to upload a folder with a lot of files

Tags: python, flask, upload

I am setting up a flask server where the user has to upload a folder with files. (I am already sure the files have correct format)
The folder is shared using Samba.
Server is where files are uploaded and where they are processed.
Client is where files are stored.
Server and client are Ubuntu.
The folder can contain a lot of files (1300 or more).

My code Option 1

html:

```
<form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name=dir webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
    <input type="submit" value="Process Files"/><br/>
</form>
```

Python:

```
all_files = request.files.getlist('dir')
print(all_files)
if all_files == []:
    print("No file found")
```

I also tried Option 2
html:

```
<form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" multiple="" name="file[]" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Process Files" >
</form>
```

Python:

```
all_files = request.files.getlist('file[]')
print(all_files)
if all_files == []:
    print("No file found")
```

**Option 1** works with folder located on the server but using shared folder html seems working fine (folder found and seems uploaded) but Python gives **"No file found"**

**Option 2** works also with shared folder but I get two **issues**:
1 I have to select all files in the folder in friendly way, I cannot ask to the user to press ctrl+A
2 It works **ONLY** if I select a subset of files in the folder. I need to upload 1300 files and it seems not working with all the files togheter

Suggestion?

Comment: You need to write a client-side function using JavaScript.

Comment: After several tests I found out new info.
Actually both options works also on shared folder but only if I consider a folder with maximum file number equal to 999.
The outcome using a shared folder with 1000 files or more is an empty array of files on python side.
Does it make sense?

Comment: The optimize way is to don't use an array to send files. I think it's better to send them one by one from client side using JSON with some infromation about file (Include file path) to the Python side and handle the rest of the work in Python side (for example: save files, create folders and anything that you want).

Comment: Thank you @Amyyazdan for you answers, but I cannot understand, can you give more details? I cannot understand why it works with a maximum number of file and with more files the array is empty

Answer (score 1):

Thanks anyone but I found the issue cause.
It was related to number of file managed from OS of client and server.
I fixed looking at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366352/etc-security-limits-conf-not-applied/370652#370652?newreg=f022beb3f52d4d7eaecbe4b19de751dd